# Facebook Comments have disappeared from all our pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

All the Facebook comments have disappeared from our site's webpages (see: http://www.around-around.com/wanted-13/).

I've run the pages through the Debugger, and it appears that they're ok (just warnings about descriptions, etc.).

But when I was trying to see if there was new code for the comment box from FB, I used the FB comment plugin creator—that's when something strange happened. The example site shows up just fine; our site is rendered with a .... Weird! Frustrating!

We've been using FB comments for over a year now, and they work pretty well. But this is really frustrating. Here's some proof: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.around-around.com/wanted-12/

Have we been...um...banned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a facebook comments plugin issue at the moment. Check this https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/383938611736678?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5269356c254c23e51751890

Hopefully it will be fixed soon.